# NoClassDefFoundError in Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

Getting an Exception when initializing Liquibase. We are using version 3.3.2 (because offline is broken in 3.3.3)

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class liquibase.servicelocator.ServiceLocator
    at liquibase.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:44)
    at liquibase.logging.LogFactory.getLogger(LogFactory.java:37)
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.<init>(SpringLiquibase.java:142)
```

We are running java 8, and it seems like this error is only visible when using sun-java-1.8.0_latest-x86_64-1.8.0-45.x86_64, not sun-java-1.8.0_latest-x86_64-1.8.0-12.x86_64.

I have created https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2372, but maybe some of you guys have some tips

Comment: I'll take a look at the issue. If it was working with one version of java it should in the other. Odd.

Comment: It might not be the java version that's causing it, but that is all I have to go after right now